# How much pressure does a toilet plunger put on the drain?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I'm assuming exactly how much weight you put on the handle in lbs but not exactly sure how it works. For example (and this is all literal) I weigh about 220lbs. If I put 100% of my weight on the handle, providing there's no air whatsoever between the inside of the rubber and the fluid, how much water pressure goes into the drain?.

Comment: What is your assessment?